# How do you start Less compiling in command line

Tags: command-line, less

I am a SASS man, but I am currently using Less for the first time as I am making a website for someone, but I'm using a template that is made using Less and includes all the files.

I've installed Less but what do I type in command line to start compiling?

I'm using a MAC and I've tried `$ lessc agency.less > agency.css` & `sudo lessc agency.less` but both return the same error given below. What am I doing wrong?

> lessc: ENOENT, open '/Users/William/Desktop/websites/grace/agency.less

Comment: You could have a look at the [official documentation](http://lesscss.org/usage/#command-line-usage-command-line-usage) :)

Comment: lessc agency.less agency.css I'm trying this and it isn't doing anything :(

Comment: Are you on a Windows machine? If yes, try as `lessc agency.less > agency.css`. If still not working try one of `lessc --version` or `lessc --help` to see if Less compiler is being called.

Comment: I tried sudo lessc agency.less agency.css and it gave me this error lessc: ENOENT, open '/Users/William/Desktop/websites/grace-building/agency.less'

Comment: Stupid question: are your sure `/Users/William/Desktop/websites/grace-building/agency.less` actually exists and has all proper permissions?

Answer (score 0):

Try `chmod +X /usr/local/bin/lessc`? (Assuming you have runned `npm i -g less` with default settings.)

Comment: I ended up setting up grunt with the less plugin on my laptop in the end, thanks four responce. What is this actually doing?

Comment: It gives `lessc` higher privilege to access the system.