# Error when tryingto compile LESS

Tags: command-line, compiler-errors, less

I'm getting this error when trying to compile

> lessc: ENOENT, open '/Users/William/Desktop/websites/grace/agency.less'

I'm using a MAC I've tried

```
$ lessc agency.less > agency.css & sudo lessc agency.less
```

same error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You don't have to create a separate question mate. Just use the "edit" link on the previous one to edit in the error message. That thread is still open and others can still help you :)

Comment: /Users/William/Desktop/websites/grace/agency.less definitely exists, and permissions are such that it's readable by the user you're running `lessc` with?

Comment: I have edited in the details provided here into your question @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31220138/how-do-you-start-less-compiling-in-command-line. Voting to close this as a duplicate.